# Are email addresses without "mailto:" allowed as IRIs?

Tags: uri, rdf, email-address, iri, turtle-rdf

In the [RDF Turtle documentation from W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#unlabeled-bnodes) I came across two examples (16 and 17) where an email address was used as an IRI:

```
_:b <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/mbox> <bob@example.com> .
```

As I understand it, email addresses are allowed as **URIs** when preceded with the appropriate scheme, i.e. `mailto:bob@example.com`. If the email address in the above example should be a valid URI then the statement should actually read:

```
_:b <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/mbox> <mailto:bob@example.com> .
```

Is this an error in the documentation or do IRIs (as opposed to URIs) not require a scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I think it makes more sense to use something like **mailto:bob@example.org** in these examples, it appears that they're still syntactically legal.  They're just resolved as relative URIs against the base.  E.g., when I use Jena's rdfcat to convert from Turtle I get the following output in Turtle and RDF/XML.

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:> .
@base <http://example.org> .

:a :hasEmail <bob@example.org>.
```

Output in Turtle and RDF/XML:

```
@prefix :      <urn:ex:> .

:a      :hasEmail  <http://example.org/bob@example.org> .
```

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="urn:ex:">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="urn:ex:a">
    <hasEmail rdf:resource="http://example.org/bob@example.org"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't expect it to be handled as relative URIs, but you are quite right. When I loaded the file using the swift library I am developing, it returned an URI I did not expect. But now I can see that it is indeed the base URI appended with the email address. :-)

Comment: Just here to say thanks too; recently stumbled upon the same thing.

Comment: PS. since it looks like the problem isn't fixed in around 8 years, is there a way to notify W3C about the problem? I tried to find a discussion forum or github repo or so but no luck.    EDIT: after just literally googling again, I created https://github.com/w3c/rdf-turtle/pull/53 . Let's see.